# How to migrate remote postgres db into my local django project?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am creating a Django project where I have to use existing database data. The existing database is Postgres and it is hosted on Aws. My goal is to copy them from Aws to my local Postgres DB and use in my project.

Thanks

Comment: If you can access the AWS database with psql, then you can access it with pg_dump - grab a dump and pg_load it to your local database. If it's an RDS database, you can probably just export a backup to S3, download it from S3 and load it into your local database.

Answer (score 0):

**You can dump the database from AWS and import locally from tools like Mysql workbench**